# Fixing Header using CSS

Tags: html, css

I am trying the fix the header on the top for my website, but while I am using position:fixed; the header is shifting to the left and rest of the content of the page is coming up. I have tried z-index and padding still header is to the left, can anyone please help in finding the solution.

Thanks

```
<body>
<div class="header_area ">
<div class=" header ">
<div class="logo  floatleft">
<img src="images/2016.png" alt="logo" width='100%' align="middle" style="border:5px solid white"/>
</div>
<div class="mainmenu floatright ">
<nav class="main-navigation pull-right hidden-xs hidden-sm">
(now some list there)
```

---

```
.header_area{}
.header
{
    position: fixed;
    z-index:1000;
    padding: 10px 0;
    margin: 0 auto;
    transition: all 1.3s ease 0s;
    -moz-transition: all 1.3s ease 0s;
    -webkit-transition: all 1.3s ease 0s;
    -o-transition: all 1.3s ease 0s;
    -ms-transition: all 1.3s ease 0s;

}
body{
    padding: 20px 10px;
    font-family: sans-serif, open-sans;
    font-size:14px;line-height:20px;color:#414141;
}
nav.main-navigation {
    position: relative;
    z-index: 9999;
    font-family: bebasregular;
}
```

Comment: try : margin-from-top and margin-from top  attributes to get specific positioning

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try to add:

```
position: fixed;
top:0; left:0; right:0;
```

Comment: Hello, it shifted the header to the right place, but the content of the page is still on the top.

Comment: Add a `margin-top: {header-height}px` on your content tag

Answer (score -1):

Try This

```
    <div class="header_area ">
<div class=" header ">
<div class="logo  floatleft">
<img src="images/2016.png" alt="logo" width='100%' align="middle" style="border:5px solid white"/>
</div>
<div class="mainmenu floatright ">
<nav class="main-navigation pull-right hidden-xs hidden-sm">
</nav>
  </div>
  </div>
```

&

```
    .header_area{
height:400px;
}
.header
{
    position: fixed;
    z-index:1000;
    padding: 10px 0;
  background-color:red;
  top:0px;
  left:0px;
  width:100%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    transition: all 1.3s ease 0s;
    -moz-transition: all 1.3s ease 0s;
    -webkit-transition: all 1.3s ease 0s;
    -o-transition: all 1.3s ease 0s;
    -ms-transition: all 1.3s ease 0s;

}
body{
    padding: 20px 10px;
    font-family: sans-serif, open-sans;
    font-size:14px;line-height:20px;color:#414141;
}
nav.main-navigation {
    position: relative;
    z-index: 9999;
    font-family: bebasregular;
}
```